# Inserting variables into an database table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have two PHP files, Database_conn and findOutMore

The PHP in database_conn:

```
<?php

$webserver = 'localhost';
$password = 'xxxx';
$username = 'xxxx';
$database = 'xxxx';



$conn = mysqli_connect( $webserver, $username, $password, $database);

if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

And the PHP in findOutMore

```
<?php
include 'database_conn.php';

$forename = $_REQUEST['forename'];
$surname = $_REQUEST['surname'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$landline = $_REQUEST['landLineTelNo'];
$mobile = $_REQUEST['MobileTelNo'];
$address = $_REQUEST['postalAddress'];
$method = $_REQUEST ['sendMethod'];

echo"<h3> These are your details </h3>";
echo"Name: ";
echo $forename;
echo " ";
echo $surname;
echo "<br>";
echo "Email: ";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo "Landline: ";
echo $landline;
echo"<br>";
echo "Mobile: ";
echo $mobile;
echo "<br>";
echo "Address: ";
echo $address;
echo "<br>";
echo"Contact Method: ";
echo $method;


$query="INSERT INTO Database_Table
    (forename, surname, postalAddress, landLineTelNo, MobileTelNo, email, sendMethod)
     values (NULL, '$forename','$surname','$address','$landline','$mobile','$email','$method')";


    if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
     echo "New record created successfully";
}

mysqli_close($conn);




?>
```

I'm not actually getting any errors and the echoes are working as they should (returning the values that were entered by the user.) But the data never actually gets entered into the database.

I thought it might be to do with the NULL at the beginning of the values, but i'm not really sure how to change it because it's supposed to be the primary key, the ID of the entry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php variable insert into database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730966/php-variable-insert-into-database)

Comment: @Abhishek Not quite, this one is a different issue.

Comment: `mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn))` 

this will tell you if you have any error in query

Comment: Share your table shema. I feel like there is an `id` with no `AUTO_INCREMENT` on it.

Comment: @yergo There is another value called expressInterestID but I didn't know how to implement it into the query

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually run the query ;)

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

`mysqli_query($conn, $query);`

I would like to point out though, that your script is incredibly insecure. You should look at using prepared statements, and potentially switch to PDO:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php